# Why doesn't "bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile()" work in UI panel?

Tags: python

Why doesn't

```
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath="D:/ddd/test_v1.blend")"
```

work in UI panel?

I need to add a new button in the render panel which sends the current file to a network location.

Comment: Is the " after the ) a typo?

Answer (score 2):

Use backslashes (\) instead of forward slashes (/). Also you need to either escape special characters, or use (') instead of (").
The following code should work:

```
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath='D:\ddd\test_v1.blend')
```

or escaping characters

```
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath="D:\\ddd\\test_v1.blend")
```